# jQuery - Element selecting and ready() method, avoiding duplicated selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, selector

I'm trying to deal with duplicated selectors in jQuery. Let's use this example, where the script is loaded in `<head>` so it's loaded before the DOM structure is.

```
var element = $(".element"); //Here, the element is null or length is 0

//element is null so ready method is not executing
element.ready(function(){

});
```

Now, if I select the element the following way, I'd be duplicating the selector:

```
$(".element").ready(function(){
   . . .
   someFunction();
   . . .
});

function someFunction(){
   $(".element").method(); //Selector duplicated here because I already used it in ready() method.
}
```

How can I avoid selectors duplication using the examples above?

Comment: never seen `$(".element").ready(function(){` syntax from what i can see in the jquery documentation you have ether the document or a img as element for the ready function https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: @madalinivascu agreed, not sure if that could be a lib or a custom method...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I get you right, but try passing the element to the function maybe ?

```
$(".element").ready(function(){
   someFunction($(this));
});

function someFunction($el){
   $el.method();
}
```

Also, as @madalinivascu said, `ready` method in an element is pretty unusual, is it a lib or a custom method of yours?

Comment: `ready()` iis a jQuery method: http://api.jquery.com/ready/. It's redundant when called on a DOM element though; it should be called on the `document` only, as such this example won't work given the OP's page structure

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I know that. I only answered because, besides the `ready` part, OP's question is about reusing the selected element.

Comment: Firstly I replied as you stated in the comment under the question you didn't know what the `ready()` function was; `... not sure if that could be a lib or a custom method`, and your last sentence is itself a question asking for confirmation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that's ok, I got your point, didn't mean to be harsh. I've answered because I think that what I suggest could be what OP wants, but I was not sure about the ready part.